# How to find (and move) all duplicate file names

Tags: bash, files, filenames

Due to moving files back and forth from my Linux PC to a Mac, I now have a few documents that duplicate. Their names **seem** identical, but apparently they are codified slightly differently, like in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150468/how-can-two-files-in-one-of-my-folders-have-the-same-name).

For instance, `ls` in a certain directory reports, among other things

```
'Voisin - Géométrie algébrique et espaces de modules.pdf'
'Voisin - Géométrie algébrique et espaces de modules.pdf'
```

These really look the same, but using the command `ls | LC_ALL=C sed -n l` as suggested in the above question, I get

```
Voisin - Ge\314\201ome\314\201trie alge\314\201brique et espaces de m\
odules.pdf$
Voisin - G\303\251om\303\251trie alg\303\251brique et espaces de modu\
les.pdf$
```

Now, I have a directory tree full of such "duplicates". Is there a way to

- find them all
- for each duplicate pair, move one of them to an external directory? (I don't want to delete them right now, just in case I mess something up)

I **think** that the content is also identical, so the `diff` should be nothing, but I am not sure, since I don't know a way to to be sure that I am running `diff` on the two copies, as the paths look identical

Comment: Have you tried any of the approaches described in [Find duplicate files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71176)?

Comment: I believe MacOS has (or had?) a different way than other *nixes to encode diacritic characters and that might have led to this situation. See for example: https://gist.github.com/JamesChevalier/8448512 ( -> https://manpages.debian.org/convmv/convmv.1 ).

Comment: You could try [normalising the names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90100/3645) and moving them to a different directory if they don't match the original filename.

Comment: Thank you all, I was able to do the task with fdupes, which has an option --delete, which lest you review the duplicate pairs and keep a single copy for each pair. I was able to distinguish the file names because the terminal renders the accents slightly differently. I made a backup before deleting just in case